# elements will not center within a div

Tags: html, css, centering

I have three elements that are coded similarly `.infobtnlg, .twitter, .infobtnsm`.

The first `.infobtnlg` is centered nicely within a div `.section1` as I want it to be, the second `.twitter` and third `.infobtnsm` are not centered within their respective sections. The width is set, the left/right margins are *auto*. I added `text-align: center;` for good measure.

What am I missing?

## [DEMO PLAYGROUND](https://jsbin.com/qepuvujumi/edit?css,output)

## HTML

```
<div class="trisection">
    <div class="section1">
        <button type="button" class="infobtnlg">The May Difference</button>
        <button type="button" class="infobtnlg">Parent Reflections</button>
        <button type="button" class="infobtnlg">Make a Gift</button>
    </div>   

    <div class="section2">
        <div class="twitter">
            <img src="/images/twitter-bl.png" alt="twitter"/>Announcements
            <hr>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="section3">
        <button type="button" class="infobtnsm" style="background-color: #003b76;">In the News</button>
        <button type="button" class="infobtnsm" style="background-color: #5a9331;">The May Way</button>
        <button type="button" class="infobtnsm" style="background-color: #ff0000;">Meet Our Teachers</button>
        <button type="button" class="infobtnsm" style="background-color: #ffcc00;">Friends of May</button>
        <button type="button" class="infobtnsm" style="background-color: #fb8d20;">The May Center</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.section1, .section2, .section3 {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 255px;
    text-align: center;
}

.infobtnlg, .twitter, .infobtnsm {
    display: block;
    width: 93%;
    margin: 6px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.infobtnlg {
    font-family: Garamond, Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: #5a9332;
    height: 77px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #3c3c3c;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 1px #3c3c3c;   
}

.twitter {
    height: 240px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url("/images/twfeed.png");
    background-size: contain;
    color: #5a9332;
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid 1px #e2dce0;

}

.infobtnsm{
    font-family: Scala, Myriadbold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: you can see the live version here: [link](http://may.lynnpatricia.com)

Comment: If you're wondering why the question has so many views, it's because it is being discussed on meta - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303724/should-i-have-handled-this-situation-better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `float: none;` to `.twitter` and `.infobtnsm` or remove `float: left;` from

```
.vista .ie8 .infobtnlg, .twitter, .infobtnsm {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Yea!  That did the trick!  Thank you!  I never would have caught that.

Comment: @LKPatricia: If this answers your question, you can accept it (the V mark on the left side, below the answer score.)

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` will help you centering text inside those `div`

```
//to center contents inside div you shoul use:
#div {
    margin:auto;
}
```

OR
you may simply choose to use bootstrap div columns which will do all your things very easy these contents will be fully responsive

```
//html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 section1">
             //section1 contents
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 twitter">
             //twitter contents
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 infobtnsm">
             //infobtnsm contents
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```